# Plot y=x^2 with tikz plot command

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wrote this article:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw[->,line width=1pt] (-2,0)--(2,0) node[right]{$y$}; 
\draw[->,line width=1pt] (0,-2)--(0,2) node[above]{$f(y)$};
\draw[blue,line width=1pt,domain=-2:2, samples=100] plot(\x,\x^2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 
 
\end{document}
```

But I got this image:

[image]

How do I fix this? I want to just use tikz plot command, not pgfplot or others.

Thanks

Comment: Just use `plot(\x,\x*\x)`.

Comment: The use of `^` in applied math should **always** be avoided.  Even `x^0.5` is slower than `sqrt(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try as suggested @projetmbc in his comment or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw[->,line width=1pt] (-2,0)--(2,0) node[right]{$y$};
\draw[->,line width=1pt] (0,-0.5)--(0,4.5) node[above]{$f(y)$};
\draw[blue,line width=1pt,domain=-2:2, samples=100] plot(\x,{(\x)^2}); % <--- observe parenthesis
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

PGF Plots can be a nice alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[ticks=none,
                    xlabel={\(y\)},
                    ylabel={\(f\big(y\big)\)}, xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4,
            every axis plot/.append style={thick},
            axis y line=center,
            axis x line=center,
            axis line style={-Triangle},
             xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
             ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
            ]
            \addplot[red,domain=-2:2,samples=500,thick]{x^2)};
                \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]